# Why are some characters shown as question marks when sending email using non-English characters?

Tags: php, email, encoding, character-encoding

I tried to send a text email with non-English characters using PHPs `mail` function. But instead my message went with funny looking garbage characters. How do I fix it?

I use this piece of code:

```
function _mail($to, $subject, $content)
{

 $headers = 'From: info@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: info@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

 mail($to, $subject, $content, $headers);
}
```

Some of the characters came out as question marks...

Comment: Please show us what you tried? And the result of a small test message, including its headers? (See http://superuser.com/questions/66082/why-do-russian-characters-in-some-received-emails-change-when-reading-in-david/66104#66104 if you don't know what I mean.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is character encoding and why should I bother with it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611455/what-is-character-encoding-and-why-should-i-bother-with-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to use the UTF-8 character set.

Add `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`, `MIME-Version 1.0` and `Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable` to the mail headers, like this:

```
$headers = 'From: info@example.com' . "\r\n" .
           'Reply-To: info@example.com' . "\r\n" .
           'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n" .
           'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
           'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' . "\r\n" .
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); // Why would you want to send this header?
```

If you would be using HTML instead of text, you’d also need to add a `META` tag to the `HEAD` of your (X)HTML mail:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: You will also need `MIME-Version: 1.0` and to `Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable` the body, as UTF-8 characters typically won't make it through the mail system intact otherwise.

Comment: But obviously, when using quoted-printable, then the message should be encoded as such as well.

Answer (score 5):

This is definitely a case for Joel's article [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

You must understand the role of character encodings before you can successfully solve this problem.

Comment: True, but not really an answer to the question IMHO; more like a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: @Mathias, this was more than I could have come up with given the original question... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

A mail wrapper such as [Swiftmailer](http://www.swiftmailer.org) might help you.

Comment: I'm using SwiftMailer, and the same problem as OP's led me here. Characters čćžšđČĆŽŠĐ each turn into a "??" (double question mark). Using `$msg = (new Swift_Message('subject'))->setFrom([me@example.com])->setTo([you@example.com])->setBody($htmlMailBody, 'text/html', 'utf-8');`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [PEAR's MAIL_MIME](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime)